# script does not work on multiple forms jsp

Tags: javascript, html

i am using this script to validate my form

```
function validate()
{
     if(trim(search.Parola.value)==="")
    { alert("Va rugam introduceti o parola");
      search.Parola.focus();
      return false;
    }
    if(search.Parola.value === search.Utilizator.value) {
    alert("Parola trebuie sa fie diferita de utilizator");
    search.Parola.focus();
    return false;
    }
    if(search.Parola.value.length < 7)
    { alert("Parola trebuie sa contina minim 7 caractere");
      search.Parola.focus();
      return false;
    }
    re = /[0-9]/;
  if(!re.test(search.Parola.value)) {
    alert("Parola trebuie sa contina cel putin un numar");
    search.Parola.focus();
    return false;
  }
  re = /[a-z]/;
  if(!re.test(search.Parola.value)) {
    alert("Parola trebuie sa contina cel putin o litera mica");
    search.Parola.focus();
    return false;
  }
  re = /[A-Z]/;
  if(!re.test(search.Parola.value)) {
    alert("Parola trebuie sa contina cel putin o litera mare");
    search.Parola.focus();
    return false;
  }
    if(trim(search.Nume.value)==="")
    { alert("Va rugam introduceti un nume");
      search.Nume.focus();
      return false;
    }
    if(trim(search.Prenume.value)==="")
    { alert("Va rugem introduceti un prenume");
      search.Prenume.focus();
      return false;
    }
    if(trim(search.CNP.value)==="")
    { alert("Va rugam introduceti un CNP");
      search.CNP.focus();
      return false;
    }
    re = /^[-]?\d*\.?\d*$/;
    if(!re.test(search.CNP.value))
    { alert("CNP Invalid");
      search.CNP.focus();
      return false;
    }
    if(search.CNP.value.length !== 13)
    { alert("CNP Invalid");
      search.CNP.focus();
      return false;
    }
    if(trim(search.Oras.value)==="")
    { alert("Va rugam introduceti orasul");
      search.Oras.focus();
      return false;
    }
}
```

And this is the code and form in JSP.

```
<%
String Utilizator = request.getParameter("Utilizator");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Database","Administrator","admin");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from utilizatori where Utilizator LIKE '%" + Utilizator + "%' ORDER BY Utilizator");
int contor =0;
if(rs!=null){

    while(rs.next()){ contor++;
    %>
    <form name="search" onSubmit="return validate();" method="get" action="doChange.jsp">
    <table width="20%" border="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>Utilizator: </td><td><%=rs.getString("Utilizator")%><td><input name="Utilizator" size="12" style="visibility:hidden" value="<%=rs.getString("Utilizator")%>"></input></td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Parola: </td><td><input type="text" size="12" name="Parola" onkeyup="return passwordStrength(this.value);" value="*****"/> </td>
                <td><div id="passwordDescription"></div>
                    <div id="passwordStrength" class="strength0"></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Nume: </td><td><input type="text" size="12" name="Nume" value="<%=rs.getString("Nume")%>"/> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Prenume: </td><td><input type="text" size="12" name="Prenume" value="<%=rs.getString("Prenume")%>"/> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Oras: </td><td><input type="text" size="12" name="Oras" value="<%=rs.getString("Oras")%>"/> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>CNP: </td><td><input type="text" size="12" name="CNP" value="<%=rs.getString("CNP")%>"/> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Rang: </td><td><select name="Rang"> 
                <option value="Utilizator" <% if("Utilizator".equals(rs.getString("Rang")))
                    out.println("selected");%> >Utilizator</option>
                <option value="Administrator" <% if("Administrator".equals(rs.getString("Rang")))
                    out.println("selected");%> >Administrator</option>
                            </select></td></tr>
    </tbody>        
    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Sterge Utilizator"/></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Aplica Modificari"/></td>
    <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="clearBox('passwordStrength')"/></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

The problem is when the query returns with more than 1 result, the script doesn't work. When it comes back with just 1 result script works just fine. What can i do to make it work on all the forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to send the form you want to validate.

```
<form name="search" onSubmit="return validate(this);"
```

In your script, replace for this:

```
function validate(search) // add the form as parameter;
{
```